# Cannot upgrade to {N} v 6.x on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, nativescript

I cannot upgrade to the latest version of NativeScript nor can I seem to uninstall it.

I initially tried npm install -g nativescript as per the upgrade instructions but tns --version still says 5.4.2. I then tried npm install -g nativescript@latest to the same result. I attempted to uninstall with npm uninstall -g nativescript then reinstall and, yet again, tns --version displays 5.4.2

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's your node version?

Comment: I'm running node v. 10.16.0

Comment: Hmm, v10.x should be good, that's the minimum requirement for CLI. Did you try clearing cache?

Comment: Thank you for the prompt responses Manoj. I was able to resolve the issue and have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue as follows:

1. `npm uninstall -g nativescript`
2. I manually removed both the tns and nativescript files(links) from /usr/local/bin
3. `npm install -g nativescript`